# Is it possible to execute the code in the try block again after an exception in caught in catch block?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I want to execute the code in the try block again after an exception is caught. Is that possible somehow?

For Eg:

```
try
{
    //execute some code
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

If the exception is caught I want to go in the try block again to "execute some code" and try again to execute it.

Comment: no, not a built-in standard way, but you can build your own

Comment: Have you tried putting it inside a while loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Try/Catch exception continue from line that caused the exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125352/try-catch-exception-continue-from-line-that-caused-the-exception), [Try-Catch and "Continue" - is this possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146248/try-catch-and-continue-is-this-possible), [Catch and Continue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113929/catch-and-continue)

Comment: @SunilKumarBM useful when making a call to a dodgy website/webservice which times out frequently or even throws 500 errors.

Comment: Also known as: **Hey, how can I use `On Error Resume Next` in C#?**

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Put it in a loop.  Possibly a while loop around a boolean flag to control when you finally want to exit.

```
bool tryAgain = true;
while(tryAgain){
  try{
    // execute some code;
    // Maybe set tryAgain = false;
  }catch(Exception e){
    // Or maybe set tryAgain = false; here, depending upon the exception, or saved details from within the try.
  }
}
```

Just be careful to avoid an infinite loop.

A better approach may be to put your "some code" within its own method, then you could call the method from both within the try and the catch as appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

If you wrap your block in a method, you can recursively call it

```
void MyMethod(type arg1, type arg2, int retryNumber = 0)
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        if (retryNumber < maxRetryNumber)
            MyMethod(arg1, arg2, retryNumber+1)
        else
            throw;
    }
}
```

or you could do it in a loop.

```
int retries = 0;

while(true)
{
    try
    {
        ...
        break; // exit the loop if code completes
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        if (retries < maxRetries)
            retries++;
        else
            throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: And then you can also run into stackoverflow due to no endpoint.

Comment: What if that function returns some value instead of void?

Answer (score 8):

```
int tryTimes = 0;
while (tryTimes < 2) // set retry times you want
{
    try
    {
        // do something with your retry code
        break; // if working properly, break here.
    }
    catch
    {
        // do nothing and just retry
    }
    finally
    {
        tryTimes++; // ensure whether exception or not, retry time++ here
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to `throw` an `Exception` if the 2nd `try` fails? Should I need another `catch` block for that? Would appreciate if you can share the syntax.

Comment: If you want throw exception, it may be easy. just write in catch (Exception ex) { if (tryTimes == 2) throw ex; }

Answer (score 4):

already answered in these (and other) links

[Better way to write retry logic without goto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148866/better-way-to-write-retry-logic-without-goto)

[Cleanest way to write retry logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563191/c-sharp-cleanest-way-to-write-retry-logic)

[How can I improve this exception retry scenario?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270271/how-can-i-improve-this-exception-retry-scenario)

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to do it (though as others have mentioned, not really recommended).  Here's an example using a file download retry to more closely match the `retry` keyword found in Ruby in VB6.

```
RetryLabel:

try
{
    downloadMgr.DownLoadFile("file:///server/file", "c:\\file");
    Console.WriteLine("File successfully downloaded");
}
catch (NetworkException ex)
{
    if (ex.OkToRetry)
        goto RetryLabel;
}
```

Comment: Seems a lot more clear than recursion or infinite loops to solve this particular problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's exactly what you potentially accomplished here - an infinite loop.  If the exception occurs, and nothing is done to resolve the underlying cause, there is no retry counter or such to stop the loop.  The `ex.OkToRetry` check might be a start to this, but it isn't clear as to if or where this would ever be set differently between `true` and `false`.

Comment: @ziesemer - the same could be said for your example which got accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know the community opinion about goto, but this is a case where I would (and do) use it. One of my applications runs a BackgroundWorker which populates an ObservableCollection. While the BackgroundWorker is running and the ObservableCollection is being populated, I allow some other functionality through the UI, but I needed to base some logic on the count of the ObservableCollection at a point in time. So I did this:

```
long resultCount;           
try_again:
try
{
    //This statement sometimes fails because ocResultList is volatile
    //while the BackgroundWorker is running

    resultCount = <ClassName>.ocResultList.LongCount();
}
catch
{
    goto try_again;
}

if(resultCount...)
{
    //do something
}
```

Does exactly what I want - and no spaghetti code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This answer doesn't seem different enough from the other proposed goto solutions already provided. Including an answer with a unique change for your situation that doesn't apply to the question is generally not helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
count = 0;
while (!done) {
  try{
    //execute some code;
    done = true;
  }
  catch(Exception e){
  // code
  count++;
  if (count > 1) { done = true; }
  }
}
```

Comment: why use flags, you are running a for loop here. so use a for loop structure.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the ole `goto`?

```
 Start:
            try
            {
                //try this
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                goto Start;
            }
```

Comment: because they lead to spaghetti code.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto

Comment: @Malky.Kid, any code leads to spaghetti code if you don't refactor.  Having a goto statement in one place is fine, and may actually cleanup your code..

Comment: @Malky.Kid you link reinforces my answer.

"goto's are appropriate in a few places, such as for jumping out of nested loops"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {  
  for (var i=0; (i < t && condition) || i === 0; i++) {
    //t is how many times you want the code to run.
    //condition should be true when there is an error.
    //The code you want to execute multiple times if it fails.
  }
} catch (e) {
  
  //The code you want to execute if the code still runs into an error after being repeated multiple times.
  
}
```

So, the code will run at least once. The condition should be true when the code results in an error, so the code will keep running until i = t, or the condition is false. If you want to execute some code after the first error, you can use `if (i > 0)`, or `if (i === 1)` to do so.